# Can nine patches be used as final images with Picasso?

Tags: nine-patch, picasso

I have a nine patch resource which shows up correctly when I put it as the background of an `ImageView` or as the main image with `fitXY` scaling. However, when I try to use it with Picasso like this:

```
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
            .into(holder.image);
```

The image gets squashed. On the other hand, if I write the code like this:

```
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://127.0.0.1/fail.png")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
            .into(holder.image);
```

The placeholder then shows up properly stretched. Another possibility is specifying a `null Uri` for `load()`. However, why is the image squashed when used with `load()`? Shouldn't the nine patch work the same as both final image and placeholder? Is there an extra flag that has to be passed to keep the properties of the nine patch?